# Print existing setoids and morphisms in Coq

Tags: coq, rewriting

I am using the [generalized rewriting features of Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual030.html).

I would like to print the setoids and morphisms currently available to `setoid_rewrite`, to understand better which relation or function is missing when rewriting fails. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `Print Instances ...` can help.

```
Require Import Setoid.
Print Instances Equivalence.
Print Instances Morphisms.Proper.
```

From the man page link you provided.

> 27.2.3  Printing relations and morphisms
>
> The `Print Instances` command can be used to show the list of currently
>   registered `Reflexive` (using `Print Instances Reflexive`), `Symmetric` or
>   `Transitive` relations, `Equivalence`s, `PreOrder`s, `PER`s, and Morphisms
>   (implemented as `Proper` instances). When the rewriting tactics refuse
>   to replace a term in a context because the latter is not a composition
>   of morphisms, the `Print Instances` commands can be useful to understand
>   what additional morphisms should be registered.